# Can I change the properties of a HttpClientHandler after the HttpClient has been created?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dotnet-httpclient

The HttpClientHandler can be used as a parameter when creating a HttpClient object, but after that there doesn't seem to be any way to access the handler without keeping a reference to it.

```
Dim Handler as New HttpClientHandler
Handler.CookieContainer = Cookies
Handler.Proxy = Proxy
Handler.UseProxy = True
Handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
Dim Client as New HttpClient(Handler, True)
```

Am I able to change the properties of a handler of an existing client object?  For example, change the Proxy or the AutoRedirect.  Would I have any issues doing this while other HttpRequestMessages are currently being processed by the client?

Comment: have you read this MSDN documentation on AutoRedirects?
[Allow Auto Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks but I'm not using HttpWebRequest but HttpClient in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The key is to change the object and not the property of the httpclient. Remember OOP 101.

Point the property to the same object but change the contents of that object.

```
 Dim Handler As New HttpClientHandler
    Dim proxy As New WebProxy()
    Dim urlBuilder As New System.UriBuilder
    Handler.Proxy = proxy
    Handler.UseProxy = True
    Handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    Dim Client As New HttpClient(Handler, True)

    urlBuilder.Host = "124.161.94.8"
    urlBuilder.Port = 80
    proxy.Address = urlBuilder.Uri

    Dim response As String = Await Client.GetStringAsync("http://www.ipchicken.com")

    urlBuilder.Host = "183.207.228.8"
    urlBuilder.Port = 80
    proxy.Address = urlBuilder.Uri

    response = Await Client.GetStringAsync("http://www.ipchicken.com")
```

Comment: Of course, pls remember that if you use this approach in a concurrent or multithreaded environment, it might not work. And needless to say, non-object value type properties may not be changed.

Answer (score 3):

After further testing it seems it is not possible, an exception is thrown when I attempt to modify the properties of the HttpClientHandler.  A new instance of HttpClient is required.