# How To Make a Proxy changing over time C# .NET Framework

Tags: c#, httpclient, http-proxy

I am doing a WebCrawler, and I would like to use a proxy in an HttpClient instance, but after a while change the proxy, either because many requests have already been made or because the proxy IP has been blocked by the site. I know I could recreate the HttpClient instance by passing it a new Proxy, but it seems like a bad practice to me. I would like to continue using the same instance, but only change the proxy that is used. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think creating new HttpClient is bad idea?

Comment: because when closing the HttpClient instance it is open for at least 4 minutes in the team processes, in addition to losing the cached information that helps the pages load more quickly

Comment: obviously everything would be re-opted with a few new requests, but I think it would be a better idea to keep the instance if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795777/can-i-change-the-properties-of-a-httpclienthandler-after-the-httpclient-has-been will this help you?